# Using pipes with FFMpeg as an input

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG library to manipulate video on user upload.

```
public async Task ManageVide(IFormFile file)
{   
   ... process file
   string command = $"-i inputFile.mp4 -vf -s 800x600 outFile.mp4";
   ...
}
```

is it possible to use memory stram as an input and output of the ffmpeg command? I read somewhere that for this can be used ffmpeg pipe. But I don't know how to structure the command

```
public async Task ManageVide(MemoryStream stream)
{   
    string command = $"-i pipe:{stream} -vf -s 800x600 test.mp4";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've been using the library [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) to work with FFMPEG. A simple example, of reading and writing from a memorystream:

```
await Cli.Wrap("Path/to/exe")
         .WithArguments(arguments)
         .WithStandardInputPipe(PipeSource.FromStream(source))
         .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStream(destinationStream))
         .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

destinationStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Even though I'm using a valid memory stream as an input (PipeSource.FromStream as a result I'm getting empty destinationStream.

Comment: Have you stepped into your code, you should probably set the destinationStream to Position 0 afterwards. The stream will read from the end and not from the start. Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: good point but its not that, length of destinationStream is 0.

Comment: if with output `test.mp4`, `destinationStream` will zero length. Try output `-f flv pipe:1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFmpegArgs](https://github.com/tqk2811/FFmpegArgs)
[Example](https://github.com/tqk2811/FFmpegArgs/blob/2b3ffdfde8ba998b8ca11815b5c4f38c43ae1b28/FFmpegArgs.Test/PipeTest/PipeTest.cs#L15)

```
using FileStream input = new FileStream(".\\Images\\img0.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
using FileStream output = new FileStream("img0_out.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);

FFmpegArg ffmpegArg = new FFmpegArg();
var videoMap = ffmpegArg.AddVideoInput(new VideoPipeInput(input, DemuxingFileFormat.mjpeg), 1, 0);
var imageMap = videoMap.ImageMaps.First().ScaleFilter().W("iw/2").H("ih/2").MapOut;
ffmpegArg.AddOutput(new ImagePipeOutput(output, MuxingFileFormat.mjpeg, imageMap));

var result = ffmpegArg.Render(c => c.WithFFmpegBinaryPath("path to ffmpeg")).Execute();
```

From arguments

```
var result = FFmpegRender
  .FromArguments(args,c => c.WithFFmpegBinaryPath("path to ffmpeg"))
  .WithStdInStream(pipein)
  .Execute();
```